# Processing messages in torquebox queue ordered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, torquebox

How to make sure `m2` would be processed only after `m1` in background?
e.g.

```
Klass.background(order:1).m1 
Klass.background(order:2).m2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope

> <@bbrowning> there's a notion of message priority, but not
>   any strict ordering of messages after they're published

Could be simulated by wrapping methods:

```
def two_in_order_bckd
  m1
  m2
end
background.two_in_order_bckd
```